# PHP Regex, extract all custom tags from text

Tags: php, regex

Simply put, I need to extract all strings enclosed in curly braces from a chunk of text, as in

Here is a {tag}, but here {tag_2} as well, and then again ...{tag_3}... here but with some trash around it.

I would like to get an array of tag, tag_2 and tag_3.
Tags can only have word characters.

I tried this:

```
$tags = array();
preg_match_all("/\{\w+\}/s", $data['text'], $tags);
```

The tags array is returned empty if run on the above fragment of text.

Edit:

I apologize for the nuisance everyone, it turns out I messed up later on. I was catching the tags via $tags, instead of $tags[0], and thus my merged array was always empty.

Comment: What does not work with your regex? Missing the `_` in tag names?

Comment: The tags array is returned as empty.

Comment: Have you tried it without escaping the curly braces? I don't think they need to be escaped.

Comment: Bart was right, I messed up later on with something else. The regex actually worked, sorry everyone!

Comment: your regex seem correct, use `/sui` modifiers for better matching, but it should work this way, the error is somewhere else, probably `$data['text']` is invalid or empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine:

```
<?php
$text = 'Here is a {tag}, but here {tag_2} as well, and then again ...{tag_3}... here but with some trash around it.';
$tags = array();
preg_match_all("/\{\w+\}/s", $text, $tags);
print_r($tags);
?>
```

produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {tag}
            [1] => {tag_2}
            [2] => {tag_3}
        )

)
```

Your `$data['text']` is probably empty.

Tested with [Ideone](http://ideone.com/OG6VY).

Comment: Indeed. The text was not empty, but I did mess up later on. Running array_unique(array_merge( /* many tag arrays here */ )) returned and empty array. Thanks! Edited main questions to explain what I did wrong. It might help someone some day.

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you're missing the (optional) underscore in your regex:

```
$tags = array();
preg_match_all("/\{[a-z]+(?:_[1-9][0-9]*)?\}/s", $data['text'], $tags);
```

Which is not the case with your regex as `\w` contains the underscore. Leaving question for the comments below.

Comment: I thought the underscore was a word character and thus included in w+?

Comment: I see. Thanks, but Bart ended up being right, the regex works, I messed it up later on while combining multiple tag arrays from different texts.

Comment: @Swader: Yes, in perl this includes the underscore: [`\w  Match "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_")`](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm)