# Regex to find the words or sentences that enclosed with custom sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace some words or some sentences and convert it to underline. I'm using PHP and find one reference: [PHP Regex, extract all custom tags from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520429/php-regex-extract-all-custom-tags-from-text)

Somehow, the case only covers for single words but not sentences. How to make the regex also can catch everything enclosed by `##` tag?

Let say my input will be such as:

> *"ll the Lorem Ipsum **##generators##** on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over **##200 Latin words##**, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always **##free from repetition##**, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc."*

Then the output will be:

> *"ll the Lorem Ipsum ____1____ on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over ____2____, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always ____3____, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc."*

Can anyone help me on how to get the regex pattern?

Comment: I think regex is `/##[^#]+##/`, then replace each with a simple `for` - HTH ;).

Comment: Yes...very good! Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Put it as an answer. It's much more efficient than a preg_match_all followed by N preg_replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the regex is:

```
/##[^#]+##/g
```

[`[Regex Demo]`](https://regex101.com/r/QmNCqG/1)

---

```
$text = 'll the Lorem Ipsum ##generators## on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over ##200 Latin words##, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always ##free from repetition##, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.';

preg_match_all('/##[^#]+##/', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches); $i++) {
  $text = preg_replace("/".$matches[$i][0]."/", "___".strval($i+1)."___" , $text, 1);
}
```

[`[PHP Demo]`](http://ideone.com/pApIf6)

Comment: Hi, just one more how to make it replace with counting number? for example...
_____1_____,__ ___2_____, etc?I'am using `preg_replace` anyway.

Comment: You need to use `for` or `foreach` over results of `preg_match_all` - please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8127288/4519059)  ;).

Comment: Or you can use `for` with `preg_replace($search, $replace, $subject, 1);` that replace just first match ;).

Comment: In this line,   `$text = preg_replace("/".$matches[$i][0]."/", "___".strval($i+1)."___" , $text, 1);`
...Errors `unknown modifier ...` since I use input `##4/5##`. Then how to solve it ? ;)

Comment: I can't understand your situation well, can you please ask it in another question? ;).

Comment: @AbuHassan for your error: you need to use `preg_quote($matches[$i][0], "/")` instead of `$matches[$i][0]` else the slash in "4/5" will end the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea using @shA.t's regex would be the use of [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) with a function that increments a variable. So it can be done without loop, which might improve efficiency a bit.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/##[^#]+##/', function($m) use (&$i) {
  return "____". ++$i ."____";
}, $str);
```

[See php demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/845555)

Comment: How to inject counter to your function? I need to use array to count..since I need to integrate to next code.

Comment: @AbuHassan This is a premium answer.  What exactly do you need that this answer doesn't provide?  Do you need `$i` outside of the function scope? -- it's there.

Comment: Yes exactly. I need to reset the counter.

Comment: @AbuHassan not sure if I understand, can't you just use `$i = 0;` to reset?

Comment: @bobblebubble for my case, `$i` value shows like `_____3_____`,`_____8_____` not start from zero.

Comment: @AbuHassan: How do you use it? Put `$i = 0;` just before the preg_replace_callback.